# jquery ajax failing due to options.data being undefined for Backbone.js collections

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js, asmx, marionette

I'm trying to get some data back from my .asmx web method but it's failing at the ajax call. Here is some of my JS code:

```
    // BaseCompositeView is basically an object extended from Marionette.CompositeView
    MyListView = App.Base.Objects.BaseCompositeView.extend({
        // contents removed for brevity
    });

    // BaseModel is basically an object extended from Backbone.Model
    MyListView.Model = App.Base.Objects.BaseModel.extend({
        // nothing here
    });

    // BaseCollection is basically an object extended from Backbone.Collection
    MyListView.Collection = App.Base.Objects.BaseCollection.extend({
        url: "../WebServices/MyService.asmx/GetUsers",

        model: MyListView.Model,

        initialize: function(options) {
            this.options = _.extend({}, this.defaults, this.options);

            this.options.data = JSON.stringify({
                "groupID": parseInt(App.Prop.get("GroupID"), 10)
            });
        }

    });

    var group_users_view = new MyListView({
        tagname: "div",
        model: new MyListView.Model(),
        collection: new MyListView.Collection()
    });
```

My web method `GetUsers` takes 1 parameter, an integer named groupID. According to this page: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-constructor, the initialize method inside MyListView.Collection is called when the Collection is created, which happens when MyListView is instantiated.

The error occurs inside the file jquery-1.12.3.js on the following line:

```
xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );
```

Here, options.data is `undefined`. However, the url property of options is correct. So why is jquery ajax not recognizing the data that I'm passing in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, there is no relationship between `this.options` and the `options` object that is passed to the Ajax calls made to your server.

If you read the source code of `fetch`, or `sync` you'll see they do not refer to `this.options` to build their `options` objects.

If you need to set your data both for reading and writing you could override `sync`. And if you want all of `this.options` to be part of what is passed to `jQuery.ajax`, then you could have something like:

```
sync: function sync(method, collection, options) {
  // It is okay for options to be undefined in the _.extend call.
  options = _.extend({}, options, this.options);
  return MyListView.Collection.__super__.sync.call(this, method, collection, options);
},
```

Comment: Thanks Louis! You're absolutely right. I needed to add a sync method to my collection. This was the missing piece of the puzzle. Basically, in here, I added a condition to check if the method is "read" and if so, then evoke a custom method that eventually calls `$.ajax()`. This custom method call is where I would pass in my `collection.options.data` which was initialized in the initialize method of my collection.